# How i can do this with the 'for' of javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to optimize my javascript code with a FOR by i can't do this and i don't know why.

My code :

```
let pokemon1 = 'premier';
let pokemon2 = 'second';
let pokemon3 = 'troisieme';
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
     console.log(pokemon[i]);
}
```

Do you know why it doesn't work ?
Thank you very much and sorry if i am a noob.

Comment: The `[ ]` is for **arrays**. Declare `pokemon` as an array and your code will work.

Comment: `console.log(eval('pokemon'+i))` hehehehe *evil grin*

Comment: Variable variables are almost always the wrong approach. Learn about data structures instead: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Comment: @FelixKling This is clearly not a duplicate, OP as a beginner in code doesn't know about arrays and was clearly wondering if something existed to handle that kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a list, you should use `[]` to define an `array` :

```
let pokemons = ['premier', 'second', 'troisième'];
for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
     console.log(pokemons[i]);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array for more information.

Also you should note that the first element of a list is 0.

So basically `pokemons[0] === 'premier` and `pokemons[2] === 'troisième'`

Answer (score 1):

You should place the pokemon in an array:

```
let pokemon = [];
pokemon[0] = "premier";
pokemon[1] = "second";
pokemon[2] = "troisieme";
for(var i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++){
 console.log(pokemon[i])
};
```

Followed by some reading time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration